# unable to test UUID

Tags: spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, h2, spock

I have a spring boot 2.6.7 app, using Liquibase, Gradle and Spock.  I have a class that uses a guid format string as the ID:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "devices")
public class Device {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?$",
             message = "Invalid id received")
    private String deviceId;

    @NotNull
    private DeviceType deviceType;    
    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate manufactureDate;
    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate activationDate;
    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate deactivationDate;
    private Status deviceStatus;
```

I have several endpoint that take this entity and persist/find/update it.  When I look at the database, I see the columns are properly populated.  So it appears to be working.

Here is my liquibase for this table:

```
- changeSet:
      id: 7
      preConditions:
        - onFail: MARK_RAN
          not:
            tableExists:
              tableName:
                devices
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: devices
            columns:
                nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: device_id
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: device_type
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
              - column:
                  name: manufacture_date
                  type: date
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
              - column:
                  name: activation_date
                  type: date
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
              - column:
                  name: deactivation_date
                  type: date
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
              - column:
                  name: internal_id
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
              - column:
                  name: device_status
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
```

However, I am now trying to wrap my code in tests and I keep running into issues that a string cannot be cast as UUID.  Here is the test:

```
given:
        def device = new Device(internalId: internalId, deviceId: deviceId,
                deviceType: deviceType, deviceStatus: deviceStatus, role: role, activationDate: activationDate, deactivationDate: deactivationDate, manufactureDate: manufactureDate)

        def result = deviceRepository.save(device)
        when:

        def isValid = deviceServices.validateDevice(result)
        then:
        isValid == testResult

        where:
        deviceId           | deviceType          | deviceStatus       | manufactureDate | activationDate  | deactivationDate | || testResult
        UUID.randomUUID() | DeviceType.EQUIPMENT | Status.ACTIVATED   | LocalDate.now() | LocalDate.now() | null               || true
```

And here is the error when the test starts by trying to insert into H2.  The field is declared as a varchar, but for some reason the stack trace mentions NumberFormat and Long values.

```
SQL Error: 22018, SQLState: 22018
2022-05-12 06:24:34.083 ERROR 42198 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Data conversion error converting "faf837fa-8584-4dff-a8d1-bd4d9a8af74c"; SQL statement:
select identity0_.device_id as scanned_1_6_, identity0_.internal_id as internal2_6_ from identities identity0_ where identity0_.device_id=? [22018-212]
```

...

```
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Data conversion error converting "9bbb114a-bb99-443c-9106-dd28210c4e7b" [22018-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.value.ValueStringBase.getLong(ValueStringBase.java:142)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertToBigint(Value.java:1645)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:1137)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertForAssignTo(Value.java:1092)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:369)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "9bbb114a-bb99-443c-9106-dd28210c4e7b" [22018-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:506)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9bbb114a-bb99-443c-9106-dd28210c4e7b"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
    at org.h2.value.ValueStringBase.getLong(ValueStringBase.java:140)
    ... 57 more
```

I feel like I have coded myself into a corner by not making the primary key a UUID, or by not having a regular ID and then using the deviceId as a UUID.  However, this is production code and I am hesitant to change the table structure via Liquibase.

Is there a way to make Liquibase or Spock work around this issue?  Again, it works fine in production, I just can't do an integration test on it (which might be a H2 limitation?)

**Update**:
I have another test that has the same behavior - unable to convert a UUID to a string attribute of the class upon persistence.  If I change the "UUID.randomUUID()" to "123" it works as expected.

Because I am seeing this only with my tests and the exception is SqlExceptionHelper I have to wonder if test H2 just can't handle the conversion that production Postgres does? I changed H2 for HSQL and get the same type of error.

Comment: You need to provide a complete definition of `identities` table and a value passed as parameter `?`. If you have a complete stack trace, it will be better to post it too. This exception looks like attempt to compare a string with textual representation of UUID with some numeric or other incompatible value.

Comment: I added the stack traces and liquibase for this table

Comment: This is neither bug nor limitation of H2. As you can see in the stack trace, this value is assigned into into column of `BIGINT` data type, but you cannot insert UUID into columns of this data type. You need to figure out why it is created with this incorrect data type by Liquibase or by something else in H2, but not in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `Device.deviceID` is `String`, but the type of `deviceId` in your Spock spec is `UUID`. So you either need to use

```java
def device = new Device(internalId: internalId, deviceId: deviceId.toString(), ...
```

or

```java
where:
deviceId                     | ...
UUID.randomUUID().toString() | ...
```

It really is as trivial as that.